# Orbeon upgrade from 3.9 to 4.5 : Customized submit for saving forms

Tags: forms, orbeon

We are upgrading from 3.9 to 4.5.

In Some 3.9 Orbeon forms, We use customized submit button for save.

This is not working in 4.5 Orbeon forms. When I click on "Submit", Its not saving the form to `orbeon_form_data` table.

Below is the source code section for the "submit",

```
<xhtml:head>
    <xforms:bind id="eoisave-btn-bind" ref="eoisave-btn" name="eoisave-btn" type="xforms:string"
                 relevant="$Bidlist_IsBidding != ''"/>
</xhtml:head>
<xhtml:body>
    <fr:button id="eoisave-btn-control" bind="eoisave-btn-bind">
        <xforms:label ref="$form-resources/eoisave-btn/label"/>
        <xforms:hint ref="$form-resources/eoisave-btn/hint"/>
        <xforms:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
    </fr:button>
    <xforms:action ev:event="DOMActivate" ev:observer="eoisave-btn-control">
        <xforms:setvalue if="xxforms:instance('fr-error-summary-instance')/valid = 'true'"
                         ref="./EOISaved"
                         value="1"/>
        <xforms:setvalue ref="./user-action">submit eoi</xforms:setvalue>
        <xforms:dispatch name="fr-save-action" target="fr-persistence-model">
            <xxforms:context name="fr:check-data-valid" select="true()"/>
        </xforms:dispatch>
    </xforms:action>
</xhtml:body>
```

And In the orbeon log, I can find the following.

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Cannot compare xs:boolean to xs:string                                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: org.orbeon.saxon.trans.XPathException                                                                      |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orbeon Forms 4.5 has simple processes which you can associate with buttons. See [Form Runner: Buttons and Processes](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner%3a-Buttons-and-Processes). The benefit of using those is that you don't rely on internals of Form Runner as you did with 3.9. Now I am not sure processes allow you to do everything you want to do at the moment, such as setting values, but I thought I would mention them.

This said, as a first step, try changing:

```
xxforms:instance('fr-error-summary-instance')/valid = 'true'
```

to:

```
xxforms:instance('fr-error-summary-instance')/valid = true()
```

Second, the `fr-save-action` is gone. This was an internal Form Runner event. Try instead:

```
<xf:action type="xpath" xmlns:process="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fr.process.SimpleProcess">
    process:runProcessByName('oxf.fr.detail.process', 'save-final')
</xf:action>
```

Note that I haven't tested this.

Comment: Hi, second suggestion worked for me. In property file "save-final" process defined ,then changed 'fr-save-action' section with the above.