# Orbeon disable custom submit to external webservice after submit

Tags: submit, orbeon

How can I disable a custom submit button after submit?

Below you can find my part of code to send:

```
<xf:trigger bind="booking-bind" id="booking">
    <xf:label>
        <xh:span>
            <xf:output value="'Send'"/>
        </xh:span>
    </xf:label>
    <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
        <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/submission_type">SendBooking</xf:setvalue>
        <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/submission_extra_info">//booking[1]</xf:setvalue>
        <xf:action type="xpath" xmlns:process="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fr.process.SimpleProcess">
            process:runProcessByName('oxf.fr.detail.process', 'send')
        </xf:action>
    </xf:action>
</xf:trigger>
```

I am using this solution: [Orbeon upgrade from 3.9 to 4.5 : Customized submit for saving forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23998478/orbeon-upgrade-from-3-9-to-4-5-customized-submit-for-saving-forms)

Comment: I reformatted the code. Also noticed there were double quotes in many places (`''`) which I replaced with single quotes (`'`).

Comment: So what is your current issue? Does it call the `send` process? Is it just that you want to disable the button?

Comment: hai Erik, it calls the send process to call a webservice. I just want to disable the send button so that users won't be able to double click it. Now it results in multiple unnecessary calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your trigger has a `booking-bind` bind. You could have a `readonly` MIP saying whether the button should be readonly. For example:

```
<bind id="booking-bind" readonly=". = 'sent'"/>
```

Then, in your action, do:

```
<xf:setvalue ref="xxf:bind('booking-bind')" value="'sent'"/>
```

This will cause the trigger to become readonly.

By the way we have an [issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2514) to tackle this better.

Comment: Thanks Erik I am going to try this out!

Comment: Hi Erik, I am testing the readonly solution. Though I might not have been clear on this matter. 

When a user clicks the button you will see above in the right corner a loading message. During this loading time/period I want to avoid double clicking. 

This solution will only work after the form is sent right?